# NoClassDefFound error on importing project from git

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I cloned a project from git having some libraries added as part of grade build . This is the gradle dependencies part of the code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "co.example.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
}
```

This is the parent build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to    all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

However on syncing the project I get the following error in logcat

> 5:51:36 PM NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jetbrains/idea/maven/model/MavenArtifactInfo:
>   org/jetbrains/idea/maven/model/MavenArtifactInfo 5:51:41 PM
>   NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog 5:51:49
>   PM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog 5:51:55
>   PM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog 5:52:10
>   PM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog 5:53:32
>   PM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog 5:56:56
>   PM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog 6:03:26
>   PM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.android.tools.idea.structure.MavenDependencyLookupDialog

Comment: show the whole build.gradle file and all parent build.gradle files in parent directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurred because I had checked offline work in gradle settings .Worked after unticking it

Comment: goto file->other settings->default settings->Build, execution and deployement->Build tools->gradle->untick offline work if it's checked .. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Checked this on another machine (non-latest DEV build). Checkbox "Maven Integration" is checked there, everything works. Updated to latest DEV build - still everything works. So, looks like, something has corrupted my config and checking

```
"Studio_File -> Settings -> Plugins" plugin "Maven Integration"
```

Is the solution.
Anyway, I highly recommend to disable "Add library dependancy" (+tooltip with clarification) menu item if corresponding plugin is disabled. Or, at least, throw another understandable exception in order to save time of user, who will face with this issue. (I expect that I'm not the last one, who faced with this)

For Brief see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182381).